# Always exists a representation $\rho$ for an arbitrary group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am studying the representations of the fundamental group of a fixed surface into PSL$_2\mathbb{R}$, and a simple question aries in me.

If $G$ is a group, and $V$ a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$, do a non trivial representation $\rho:G\longrightarrow \text{End}(V)$ always exists?

What I mean is the following, if I take a group $G$ wild as soon as possible, am I able to find a representation in End$(V)$?

If not; could you give an example of a group which don't admit a representation? And which are the minimal hyphotesis on $G$ such that it admit a representation?

What happens if we consider PSL$_2\mathbb{R}$ instead of End$(V)$?

Comment: A trivial representation ($\rho\left(g\right) = \operatorname{id}$ for all $g$) always exists. :)

Comment: Ok you right; but I mean non trivial representation :) no I edit my post, thank you for the remark.

Comment: Well, the trivial group has no nontrivial representations. And the cyclic group of order $3$ has no nontrivial representations of dimension $1$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: The one-dimensional representations of $G$ are dual to the abelianization $G/[G,G]$. If there is even one nontrivial one-dimensional representation, then one may take direct sums of it to get a nontrivial representation of any dimension. A group which has trivial abelianization - in which case this idea won't work - is called a perfect group.

Comment: In the general semisimple situation though (say $|G|$ is invertible in the scalar field, so Maschke's applies) a vector space $V$ can be equipped with a nontrivial linear action of $G\iff \dim V$ is expressible as a sum of dimensions of nontrivial irreducible representations (use the same direct sum idea to prove this). Note that the set of irreducible representations depends on the scalar field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is finite and $\dim(V) \geq |G|$, then the permutation representation of $G$ exists and can be extended to a representation of $G$ on $End(V)$ (by putting zeroes in the extra columns and rows of the $\rho (g)$ matrices).

Comment: You mean $\dim V \geq |G|$, don't you?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant

Comment: And what happens if $G$ is not finite?

Comment: This construction can be done even for infinite groups. In such a case $V$ is not a finite dimensional vecor space (the basis of $V$ is in bijection with $G$).